# Python Django - form.is_valid() keeps throwing unicode object has no attribute get error

Tags: python, django, forms, unicode

I am creating a form for a custom user type. But each time I submit the form to test it, it returns an error that says the unicode object has no attribute get error.

forms.py:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for registering a new account.
    """
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                label="Password")
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                label="Password (again)")
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_second_year')

    def clean(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

models.py:

```
class StudentManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, firstname, lastname, email, is_second_year, password, is_officer=False, hours=0, points=0):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Student must have an email address.")

        newStudent = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            firstname=firstname,
            lastname=lastname,
            is_officer=is_officer,
            is_second_year=is_second_year,
            hours=hours,
            points=points
        )

        newStudent.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return newStudent
    def create_superuser(self, firstname, lastname, email, password, is_second_year, is_officer=True, hours=0, points=0):
        newSuperStudent = self.create_user(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            firstname=firstname,
            lastname=lastname,
            is_officer=is_officer,
            is_second_year=is_second_year,
            hours=hours,
            points=points,
            password=password
        )
        newSuperStudent.is_admin = True
        newSuperStudent.save(using=self.db)
        return newSuperStudent


class Student(AbstractBaseUser):
    firstname = models.CharField(verbose_name="First Name", max_length=30, default="")
    lastname = models.CharField(verbose_name="Last Name", max_length=30, default="")
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='Email Address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        default=''
    )
    is_officer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_second_year = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Check this box if this is your second year in NHS")
    hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    points = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

views.py:

```
def sign_up(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            print "money"
            form.save()
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/sign_up_success/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = RegistrationForm()
    return render_to_response('events/sign_up.html', args)
```

Error Location within the .is_valid() method:

```
 field_value = self.cleaned_data.get(field, None)
```

My guess is that for some reason, the cleaned_data attribute of my form is a unicode object rather than a dictionary. But I have no clue why this is so!

Comment: Please post your full traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clean` must return the full `cleaned_data` dictionary, not a single string field.